# Apache mod_deflate doesn't compress javascript/css

Tags: apache, xampp, mod-deflate

I'm trying to make Gzip compression work on xampp, right now this is in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype

</IfModule>
```

The HTML file gets compressed, but nothing happens to the JavaScript and CSS files. Anyone know why? How to fix this? (if it's even possible)

Comment: `mod_deflate` installed and enabled?

Comment: Jup, as I said, compression works on html files, but on nothing else

Comment: Does the mime-types for javascript and css files that apache reports match up with the types you're adding?

Comment: @Crinsane You can try going to [here](http://web-sniffer.net/) and doing a HEAD request for a css and js file, or you can try looking for `AddType` for js and css in server config

Comment: Found out the browser still used a cached version of the js and css files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... stupid fault... browser still used cached versions...